# Bash or GoogleCL: new line in a string parameter

Tags: python, bash, command-line

HI, I am using [GoogleCL version 0.9.11](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) to upload videos to Youtube. My OS is CentOS 5.5 and Python 2.5.

One of the string parameters contain new line "\n", and it cant display properly.

```
google youtube post ~/videos/cat-falls-down-stairs.avi Comedy --tags "currency of the internet" --summary "Poor whiskers takes a tumble.\nShe's fine, though, don't worry."
```

The summary page display as:

```
Poor whiskers takes a tumble.\nShe's fine, though, don't worry.
```

But I want:

```
Poor whiskers takes a tumble.
She's fine, though, don't worry.
```

The "\n" wont work. Who has a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Bash's [`$''`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) construct to expand escape sequences before they are passed to googlecl.

```
google youtube post ~/videos/cat-falls-down-stairs.avi Comedy \
    --tags 'currency of the internet' \
    --summary $'Poor whiskers takes a tumble.\nShe'\''s fine, though, don'\''t worry.'
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084389/bash-variable-in-single-quote

Answer (score 1):

Just put an acutal newline in side the string. Bash knows how to handle multi-line strings if you just press enter in the middle of them.

```
google youtube post ~/videos/cat-falls-down-stairs.avi Comedy --tags "currency of the internet" --summary "Poor whiskers takes a tumble.
She's fine, though, don't worry."
```

Comment: I'd love to format this better to avoid the horizontal scrolling, but I think it will detract from the main point of the answer.

Comment: "Just put an acutal newline in side the string."??? How? When I key down the "Enter" key, the command runs and issues an error. Cant key down the "Enter" key when you type a command. I am afraid.

Comment: @DocWiki: is it possible that you pasted the command into the command line, then moved to the middle of the string and hit enter? Bash will execute the command automatically if you do that. (Even if you paste everything except for the last quotation mark, then move to the appropriate place in the line and hit enter, you still won't get a newline where you want.)

Comment: @DocWiki: However, if you paste only the stuff that belongs before the newline (making sure to leave mismatched quotation marks), then hit enter, then type/paste the rest of the command, in that case, you'll get a newline in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

googlecl is a python application. Escape the `\n` with a `\` and have your string as `"Poor whiskers takes a tumble.\\nShe's fine..."` . This should perhaps help.