# How do I use variables in single quoted strings?

Tags: string, bash, shell, echo

How do I echo a variable inside single quotes?

```
echo 'test text "here_is_some_test_text_$counter" "output"' >> ${FILE}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/6862601) as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084389/bash-variable-in-single-quote

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Variables are expanded in double quoted strings, but not in single quoted strings:

```
 $ name=World

 $ echo "Hello $name"
 Hello World

 $ echo 'Hello $name'
 Hello $name
```

If you can simply switch quotes, do so.

If you prefer sticking with single quotes to avoid the additional escaping, you can instead mix and match quotes in the same argument:

```
 $ echo 'single quoted. '"Double quoted. "'Single quoted again.'
 single quoted. Double quoted. Single quoted again.

 $ echo '"$name" has the value '"$name"
 "$name" has the value World
```

Applied to your case:

```
 echo 'test text "here_is_some_test_text_'"$counter"'" "output"' >> "$FILE"
```

Comment: Alternatively, `echo "test text \"here_is_some_test_text_$counter\" \"output\""`... Escape the double quotes you don't want the shell to interpret.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to quote ``"$FILE"``.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko-A. [Is it necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748)

Comment: @JoshDetwiler Long story short: **yes**. The answer you linked is fine and goes into all the details, but quoting a variable never hurts and most often quotes are indeed *required* for proper behavior.

Comment: *If you can simply switch quotes* not possible if you're using quote-surrunded JSON (JSON  requires double quotes for its values)

Comment: ya know. In my case you have to put something in the variable for it to work. 

Answer (score 7):

use printf:

```
printf 'test text "here_is_some_test_text_%s" "output"\n' "$counter" >> ${FILE}
```

Comment: Please quote ``"$FILE"``.

Answer (score 4):

Use a heredoc:

```
cat << EOF >> ${FILE}
test text "here_is_some_test_text_$counter" "output"
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

The most readable, functional way uses curly braces inside double quotes.

```
'test text "here_is_some_test_text_'"${counter}"'" "output"' >> "${FILE}"
```

Comment: Duplicate of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer from 10 months back

Comment: @JonasBerlin: Not exactly a duplicate, but, given that the alleged improvement is _incidental_ to making the original solution work, this should be a _comment_, not an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the reputation to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another pair of single quotes arround the variable solved my problem.

For your case:

`echo 'test text "here_is_some_test_text_'$counter'" "output"' >> ${FILE}`

Answer (score 0):

with a subshell:

```
var='hello' echo 'blah_'`echo $var`' blah blah';
```

Comment: Does not work, echoes ```blah_`echo $var` blah blah```

Comment: You're right, needs to be surrounded by double quotes instead of simple quotes. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Your new answer will compress any whitespace in `$var`.. please see Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer..

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo). You'll be fine with `'blah_'"$var"' blah blah.'` But that's already in Ignacio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$ counter=1 eval echo `echo 'test text \
   "here_is_some_test_text_$counter" "output"' | \
   sed -s 's/\"/\\\\"/g'` > file

cat file
test text "here_is_some_test_text_1" "output"
```

**Explanation**:
Eval command will process a string as command, so after the correct amount of escaping it will produce the desired result.

It says execute the following string as command:

```
'echo test text \"here_is_some_test_text_$counter\" \"output\"'
```

Command again in one line:

```
counter=1 eval echo `echo 'test text "here_is_some_test_text_$counter" "output"' | sed -s 's/\"/\\\\"/g'` > file
```

Answer (score 0):

Output a variable wrapped with single quotes:

```
printf "'"'Hello %s'"'" world
```

Comment: Doesn't work if your variable contains literal single quotes, so this isn't reliable with unknown values.