# How to include data from a variable in an interactive MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, shell, variables, interactive

I'm trying to write a shell script that dumps all tables with a user specified table prefix. The following is part of the script:

```
variable=vardata
mysql -u user -p -N information_schema -e "SELECT table_name FROM tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' AND table_name LIKE 'test_$variable%'"
```

Accessing the variable can't work like this, because of the hard quotes in the SQL statement, but how else can I do it? I tried MySQL variables @var, but that also doesn't seem to work with the LIKE operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: Variable in single quote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084389/bash-variable-in-single-quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
variable=vardata
sql_stmt="SELECT table_name FROM tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' AND table_name LIKE 'test_"$variable"%'"
mysql -u user -p -N information_schema -e "$sql_stmt"
```

Hope this works

**UPDATED**: Per comment from J.Doe

Comment: mysql -u user -p -N information_schema -e "$sql_stmt"  <- This works. Thanks a lot!